# mongodb LockException error on cache clear

Tags: mongodb, symfony, odm

I have recently added `"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.5"`, to my symfony 3.4 project but once I want to run any command or making first attempt to call an end point I get 
`LockException.php line 69:`

`Invalid version field type integer. Version field must be int or date.`
wondering if some one could help me
Exception trace:
  `at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/LockException.php:69
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LockException::invalidVersionFieldType() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:2074
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->setVersionMapping() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:1461
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->mapField() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php:77
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadata->mapField() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php:218
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver->addFieldMapping() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Driver/XmlDriver.php:173
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver->loadMetadataForClass() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:77
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:160
 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:304
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:183
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:89
 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:78
 Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->getClassesForProxyGeneration() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:66
 Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:52
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:681
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:135
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:152
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->reboot() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:199
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->warmup() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/CacheClearCommand.php:133
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand->execute() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:981
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:86
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:254
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:74
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/neda/project/community/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:147
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/neda/project/community/bin/console:28`

Comment: please paste here also stack trace of that exception - you should see it when you run your command with additional option "-vvv"

Comment: thank I will add the stack to my question since here is character limited

Answer (score 0):

You are using versioning in one of your documents (a field mapped as `@Version`) and its type is not an int nor a date, as the exception states. `Int` and `date` field types are the only ones you can use combined with `@Version` ([docs for reference](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2/reference/annotations-reference.html#version))

Comment: I see you're using XML, any occurences of a `version` attribute then? Versioning is the only path you can enter to get this exception while loading metadata: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/1.2.x/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L1459